# How to create multiple terminals in python (VScode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

how to create multiple terminals in python (VScode) to run the same code in several terminals simultaneously the same code. I also need to know how to open several .py files simultaneously too (running at the same time).

I found some ways to run .py files similar to:

```
start /b python bot_1
```

or

```
start bot_1
start bot_2
```

or even imports of these bots without using patch

```
import bot1, bot2
```

but it does not work.
I tried with shell but I couldn't get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try `multiprocessing` to deliver data to other cpu, run them at same time.

Notice that deliver data will spend some time.

If your bots are simple or don't need to `sleep`, run them one by one will be faster.

bot1.py

```
from time import sleep

def bot1(num):
    sleep(2)
    print(f'This is bot1, num: {num}')
```

bot2.py

```
from time import sleep

def bot2():
    sleep(2)
    print('This is bot2')
```

main.py

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import bot1, bot2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_list = []
    for i in range(5):
        process_list.append(mp.Process(target=bot1, args=(i,)))
    process_list.append(mp.Process(target=bot2))

    for p in process_list:
        p.start()
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()
```

output

```
[Running] python -u "d:\Documents\python\projects\test\main.py"
This is bot1, num: 0
This is bot1, num: 2
This is bot1, num: 3
This is bot1, num: 1
This is bot2
This is bot1, num: 4

[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.257 seconds
```

Comment: it didn't work, but I got the idea of ​​importing the bot, but that didn't work

Comment: Can you provide the traceback message?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can click the plus sign on the terminal to open a new terminal.

While running a file, you can manually enter the code execution file in the other terminal.

For example,

```
from time import sleep


def a():
sleep(10)
print("sleep")

a()
```

For one, we can use `Run Python File`

[image]

For another, we can use command `python testA.py` in another terminal.
[image]

Comment: i got it, but what i need is for this to be done automatically, 
for example: 20 terminals running the same code at the same time all created automatically after starting the code.

Comment: @lucas lima Vscode can open multiple terminals, but it cannot run the code in a new terminal when you run python file. You can manually create terminals and execute files by using commands.

Comment: so i could run other files with selenium using commands?

Comment: Vscode uses the built-in terminal of windows, and there is no conflict with selenium. You can do this.